# How to reduce the number of iterations in Benders Decomposition for LP?

Tags: linear-programming

I am using Benders Decomposition(BD) to solve a linear problem(**all decision variables are continuous variables**). Though it solved this problem correctly, the number of iterations is up to 315 and it will take too much time. I have searched some methods to accelerate BD but I found they are mainly for MIP.

> So I am wondering is there any good way to reduce the number of iterations in a linear problem.

Comment: You might find some useful answers here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benders-decomposition